# Asp.net 7 core. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Unexpected end of request content

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, nginx, kestrel

Sometimes, handling request in controller

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api")]
public class FrontWcController : ControllerBase
{
[HttpPost("change")]
    public IActionResult GetFromFrontSendToErp(ParametrsForButton requestData)
    {
        string wcGuid = requestData.WcGuid;
        string operation = requestData.Operation;
        string skusSerial = requestData.SkusSerial;
        string boxSerial = requestData.BoxSerial;
        int actionNumber = requestData.ActionNumber;
        int operationNumber = requestData.OperationNumber;
        int checkBox = requestData.CheckBox;

        string actionHumanString = "Undefined";

        switch (actionNumber)
        {
            case 1:
                actionHumanString = "Started";
                break;
            case 2:
                actionHumanString = "Pause";
                break;
            case 3:
                actionHumanString = "Finished";
                break;
            case 4:
                actionHumanString = "Exeption";
                break;
            case 5:
                actionHumanString = "Started";
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Cant change status. Set to default");
                break;
        }

        DateTime dateTimeOfOperation = DateTime.UtcNow;
        
        MainIncomingChangesSaverList.IncomingChangesSaversList.Enqueue(new IncomingChangesSaver()
        {
            WcGuid = wcGuid,
            Operation = operation,
            SkusSerial = skusSerial,
            BoxSerial = boxSerial,
            ActionNumber = actionNumber,
            OperationNumber = operationNumber,
            CheckBox = checkBox,
            ActionHumanString = actionHumanString,
            DateTimeOfChange = dateTimeOfOperation
        });

        using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
        {
            if (actionNumber == 2 || actionNumber == 5)
            {
                Pause pause = new Pause(){wcGuid = wcGuid, Operation = operation, BoxSerial = boxSerial, SkusSerial = skusSerial, ActionNumber = actionNumber, DateTime = dateTimeOfOperation};
                db.Pauses.Add(pause);
            }
            Change change = new Change() { wcGuid = wcGuid, Operation = operation, BoxSerial = boxSerial, SkusSerial = skusSerial, ActionNumber = actionNumber, DateTime = dateTimeOfOperation };
            db.Changes.Add(change);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        // return StatusCode(200);
        return Ok("Request successfuly completed");
    }
```

throw exception:

ail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
Connection id "0HMU4QP2AD7CS", Request id "0HMU4QP2AD7CS:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Unexpected end of request content.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1ContentLengthMessageBody.ReadAsyncInternal(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpRequestStream.ReadAsyncInternal(Memory`1 destination, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token) at System.Text.Json.Serialization.ReadBufferState.ReadFromStreamAsync(Stream utf8Json, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean fillBuffer) at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadFromStreamAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BodyModelBinder.BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder.BindModelAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IModelBinder modelBinder, IValueProvider valueProvider, ParameterDescriptor parameter, ModelMetadata metadata, Object value, Object container) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerBinderDelegateProvider.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<CreateBinderDelegate>g__Bind|0>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location --- at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)

Users quickly press buttons on the front, up to 1 time per second. Every time you click from the frontend, an ajax request is made.

Comment: Check frontend request. 1. content-type correspond request body.
2. request body is correct, by example, if it JSON body is correct json string.
3. check you default serialiser.

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I'm a newbie

Comment: Hi @AlexeyBurakov, how do you call this api?  Have you set the breakpoint and check which line makes such error? Or it gives the error message without hitting the endpoint?

Comment: @Rena <br/>
fetch(mainUrl + "change", requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(function (result) {
            // console.log(result)
        })
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
The error manifests itself irregularly, in most cases everything is ok

Comment: Hi @AlexeyBurakov, does this ajax call hit your endpoint? If not, could you pls share more info about the data you pass by ajax and what's the `ParametrsForButton` model design?

Answer (score 1):

it seems a dotnet bug, see https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/23949, you can use a middleware to catch the Exception, https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/23949#issuecomment-950471048

Comment: So, the bug is not fixed yet?!

Comment: not yet, the issue is still opening.